# Building WITH_QT gives various errors

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I'm building OpenCV 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

I'm including many libraries (extra modules, TBB, Eigen, etc..) and everything is compiling and working as it should
The only problem I have is when slecting the WITH_QT option
Although it is installed and the executable path is configured, I even tested creating QT apps, but it still gives me unfound reference errors when compiling the opencv_contrib examples

```
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::KeyPointSettingsSelector'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::SlotQString'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::view::TranslationMatchView'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `CvButtonbar::staticMetaObject'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::gui::FilterCallTab'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::view::ImageView'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::MatchSettingsSelector'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::Slot'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::MatchManagement'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `typeinfo for cvv::qtutil::MatchSelection'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::OverlayFilterWidget'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::ChangedPixelsWidget'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `cvv::qtutil::SignalMatRef::signal(cv::Mat&) const'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::gui::OverviewPanel'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `cvv::qtutil::Signal::signal() const'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::STFLQueryWidget'
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para `vtable for cvv::qtutil::KeyPointSelectionSelector'
```

Any workaround?

UPDATE:

Tried to disable "cvv" module: cmake -DBUILD_opencv_cvv=OFF

and now I'm getting:

```
[ 47%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/optflow-example-motempl
../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinida para .vtable for CvWinProperties' ../../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: refer�./../lib/�libopencv_world.so.3.2.0ncia: indefinidarefer paravtable for �CvCheckBox�ncia'
indefinida. para./ ..vtable/ libfor/ libopencv_world.so.3.2.0CvWinProperties: ' refer.�./�.ncia. indefinida/lib /libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referênciapara indefinida para vtable for CvPushButton' .vtable. for/../lib/libopencv_world.so.3.2.0: referência indefinidaCvCheckBox ' paravtable for GuiReceiver'
```

Comment: looks ike you're not linking to qtutil.

Answer (score 0):

I had to turn off opencv_cvv and opencv_world
-DBUILD_opencv_cvv=OFF
-DBUILD_opencv_world=OFF